# swiftui Properties binding to each other and swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

in my Swiftui project I have a picker and a graph image with a dropped pin.  When I update the picker the pin changes location after transforming for coordinates.  I would also like to let the user move the pin and have it appropriately update the picker selection.  How do I bind the picker selection and pin location without causing an infinite loop(user moves pin which updates picker which then tries to update pin and so on)

Currently I have two observable classes - AppState and GraphState - Heres a sample of what I'm doing.  Tried to simplify it, so I may have missed some details

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pickerSelection:String
    var graphState = GraphState()

init() {
    GraphStateSubscribe()
}

func GraphStateSubscribe(){
        graphState.state = self
        $pickerSelection.subscribe(self.graphState)
    }
}


class GraphState:ObsevableObject{

    @Published var pinLocation: {
    willSet {
        state!.pickerSelection = newValue
    }

    var state:AppState?




/// func placePinCode here


}

extension GraphState:Subscriber{
typealias NewSelectionValue = String
typealias Input = NewSelectionValue

typealias Failure = Never

func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
    print("Received graphState subscription")
    subscription.request(.unlimited)
}

func receive(_ input: (NewSelectionValue)) -> Subscribers.Demand {

    placePin(input)
    return .none
}

func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Never>) {
    print("completed graphState subscription")
}
```

}

these are each bound to swiftuiviews which then draw from and update the individual state classes on user interaction.  The reason I separate them is because each state class also has other functions its doing.

I found a somewhat related solution in RxSwift - https://dev.to/vaderdan/rxswift-reverse-observable-aka-two-way-binding-5e5n

Whats the best way to keep these two properties in sync?

thanks for your help

Comment: If both should have one value then probably there is sense to separate that property in dedicated place to follow *single source of truth*.

Comment: Well the pickervalue and pin location are dependent on each other but pin location is based on the views size which is pulled into graphstate during initialization of that view.  On iPhone graph is only visible in landscape view while on iPad all the views are visible